# OpenVPN clients not able to connect on certain ports

Tags: networking, routing, openvpn, linux-networking, port

**Problem:**

I have an OpenVPN instance running on `UDP/123`. I have a VPS using the same port-protocol combination without issue, however my home VPN does not allow me to connect.

**Extra Info:**

Router ports `123 UDP/TCP` are open, no service (except OpenVPN) is running on `UDP/123`

running `nc -u host 123` just hangs forever, while `nc host 123` responds almost immediately with

```
host.name.net [x.x.x.x] 123 (ntp) : Connection refused
```

Openvpn instance runs with no error in logs. No connection can be established to it from any client (Android, Linux)

I have tested other ports e.g. `UDP/2999` which connects almost instantly, ofcourse this port is opened in the router firewall aswel, the same as `UDP/TCP 123`

**Configs:**

client.ovpn

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote host.name.net 123
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ca ca.crt
cert client.crt
key client.key
ns-cert-type server
comp-lzo
verb 3
```

server.conf

```
port 123
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
dh dh2048.pem
server 192.168.10.0 255.255.255.0
push "redirect-gateway def1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
client-to-client
keepalive 10 120
comp-lzo 
user nobody
group nogroup
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
log         openvpn.log
verb 3
push "remote-gateway host.name.net"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
```

**Client Log Connection Output:**

```
Thu Apr  6 23:16:20 2017 OpenVPN 2.4.0 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Feb 10 2017
Thu Apr  6 23:16:20 2017 library versions: OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016, LZO 2.08
Thu Apr  6 23:16:20 2017 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]x.x.x.x:123
Thu Apr  6 23:16:20 2017 Socket Buffers: R=[212992->212992] S=[212992->212992]
Thu Apr  6 23:16:20 2017 UDP link local: (not bound)
Thu Apr  6 23:16:20 2017 UDP link remote: [AF_INET]x.x.x.x:123
Thu Apr  6 23:17:20 2017 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
Thu Apr  6 23:17:20 2017 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
Thu Apr  6 23:17:20 2017 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, process restarting
Thu Apr  6 23:17:20 2017 Restart pause, 5 second(s)
Thu Apr  6 23:17:26 2017 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]x.x.x.x:123
Thu Apr  6 23:17:26 2017 Socket Buffers: R=[212992->212992] S=[212992->212992]
Thu Apr  6 23:17:26 2017 UDP link local: (not bound)
Thu Apr  6 23:17:26 2017 UDP link remote: [AF_INET]x.x.x.x:123
Thu Apr  6 23:18:27 2017 TLS Error: TLS key negotiation failed to occur within 60 seconds (check your network connectivity)
Thu Apr  6 23:18:27 2017 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
Thu Apr  6 23:18:27 2017 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, process restarting
Thu Apr  6 23:18:27 2017 Restart pause, 5 second(s)
```

**Note** once again, chaning only the server and client port from 123 to 2999 results in a working connection, but I require 123.

When changing back to 123, then no client can connect.

**Note** too that [2999,123,...] UDP/TCP are open in the router firewall.

Any suggestions why this occurs?